# Filtering out unwanted tuples

Tags: haskell

So here's what I'm trying to do. I have two lists (of tuples) and I want to take one list and remove all instances of it from the other list.

```
filly :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
filly x = filter(\(a, b) -> a /= fst x && b /= snd x || a /= snd x && b /= fst x)

remaining :: [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
remaining [] remain = remain
remaining h remain = remaining h2 (filly (head h) remain)
   where h2 = tail h
```

However it doesn't quite work.
When I input double ints it still removes them and that isn't what I want. 
e.g.

```
remaining [(1,2)] [(1,2),(3,4),(2,2)]
returns [(1,2),(3,4)]
```

Why does it remove the (2,2) but not the (1,2). I would like it to remove the 1,2 and nothing else

I really can't see where I'm going wrong

Comment: Your predicate is wrong. The simplest way to fix it is `filly x = filter (\t -> not $ t == x || x == swap x)`

Comment: Urelated style comment: don't be afraid to use pattern matching. E.g. `remaining (x:xs) remain = remaining xs (filly x remain)` can be easier to read than using `head,tail`. Further, `head,tail` put the burden on you to ensure that the list is nonempty (or they will raise an exception), while pattern matching does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does it remove the (2,2) but not the (1,2).

Your predicate is wrong:

```
(\(a, b) -> a /= fst x && b /= snd x || a /= snd x && b /= fst x)
```

This predicate [is equivalent to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```
(\(a, b) -> not $ (a == fst x || b == snd x) && (a == snd x || b == fst x)
```

But that's not what you meant, as this will filter any `(a,a)` and `(b,b)`, but *not* `(a,b)`. You meant

```
(\(a, b) -> not $ (a,b) == x || (b,a) == x)
-- or, equivalent: (\(a, b) -> (a, b) /= x && (b, a) /= x)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

```
filter (\tuple -> tuple `notElem` listA) listB
```

`notElem` returns if an element doesn't exist inside a list (the backticks make it an infix function, like how + or - works). So you're just filtering the contents of `listB` so that it only has tuples that aren't in `listA`.

Edit: After considering Zeta's comment, I may have misinterpreted your question. To clarify, if you wanted `remaining [(1,2)] [(1,2),(2,1)]` to return `[]` then you could also check that the swapped tuple also isn't inside the list:

```
import Data.Tuple

filter (\p -> p `notElem` ys && swap p `notElem` ys) xs
```

Comment: For convenience the Prelude also defines `notElem`

Comment: Thanks used that instead.

Comment: Note that this won't work, as this will filter only `(a,b)`, but not `(b,a)` from the list.

Comment: @Zeta Hmm, yeah I think you're probably right. My read on "take one list and remove all instances of it from the other list" was this implementation, but I can't imagine why @Sprout would implement `filly` like they did if they wanted that.